# Server error : not able to share project with different google domain email id

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a project on Gmail id and shared with email id that is on other google domain (abc@mydomain1.com). When I try to accept invitation it shows

```
Server Error. There is a problem at our end.
```

[image]

But when I do same with email id (xyz@mydomain2.com).It is working. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Developer console was disabled for Google App Domain. So I have performed following steps to sort out this problem

```
1) Go into your domain administration @ https://admin.google.com/AdminHome

2) Click the "More controls" link at the bottom the page

3) Within the panel that reveals, click "More Google Apps"

4) Select checkbox for "Google Developers Console" (hexagon nut logo)

5) In the top-left you will see an icon to "Turn ON services"

6) Confirm your choice
```